# Activate and Remove jQuery Mobile listview based on screensize

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, resize

I want to be able to use jQuery Mobile "listviews" format only if the screen width is below a certain value (say 480px).  If the screen is larger it shows the regular html list (which I would style with my own css).

I'm close but the problem that I'm having is that my code only works on one resize.

See my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5Qv4Y/ 
and drag the preview window in less than 480 and see the regular list turn into the JQM list.  Bring it back to greater than 480 and it goes back to regular... but then it doesn't work anymore.  I'd like to be able to go back and forth and have the list change each time.

Here is my code:

```
// fire if window is 480 or less on load
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
        if (windowsize <= 480) {
            $("ul").listview();

        }

 // change on screen resize (in theory)   
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var windowsize = $(window).width();
        if (windowsize <= 480) {
            $("ul").listview();

        }

        if (windowsize > 480) {
            $("ul").removeClass("ui-listview");
            $("li").removeClass("ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c");
        }


    });
```

Why doesn't this work correctly?

Comment: Nevermind - css @media queries for the win: http://jsfiddle.net/5Qv4Y/2/

Comment: Put solved in the title.